# how to convert centos server to docker base image

Tags: docker, centos, redhat

we have a server which hosts number of apps, I am exploring a possibility where we can create and upload a base image every time we deploy a new app on the server. is this a valid approach and is it possible.

```
root@sl2o2app301:~$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg01-root   58G  4.6G   54G   8% /
devtmpfs               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  7.8G   28K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  7.8G  835M  7.0G  11% /run
tmpfs                  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              247M  152M   96M  62% /boot
tmpfs                  1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1518

root@sl2o2app301:/etc$ cat redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

Comment: What's the single process your container would run?  If there was a security issue in a library involved in this setup, how would you rebuild the image?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do the opposite of the intended purpose of containers. With containers, I believe, the idea is to have a server with minimal configuration that runs different containers, which images encapsulate all the configuration required for every application. As mentioned in the comment above, a container is more like a process rather than a virtual machine with an operating system and several applications running on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an invalid approach if you want to use docker.
Docker is more like isolated running app (container) not operating system.

But Docker is not a silver bullet, and in some cases, you need to use golden images for server management.

For creating of golden server images you may use [packer](https://www.packer.io/) for production and/or [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for local development images

However, you still may want to use a dockerized approach. in this case, you need to split your server into the set of docker containers. One application + its dependencies in one container. This will be a valid usage of the tool.

If you want to run them altogether from one command it is good to evaluate [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) onboarding.